# How to use Aurelia bundle for a MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundle, aurelia

I am trying to use Aurelia bundle --force command with an Aurelia app hosted within a page of my MVC application.

When i try to run the command, I keep getting the following error:

```
info: Creating bundle ...
fs.js:549
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\...\WebFrontend\index.html'
```

How do you change the location where aurelia bundle looks up for the index.html? My index.html is not in the root of the website. Furthermore, my aurelia 'index.html' is actually named settings.cshtml

UPDATE:

I finally got it working by putting my entire Aurelia app within a sub folder of my MVC app. Using post build events in my project, I got Aurelia-CLI to bundle my app. Within my setting.cshtml, I basically just reference the config.js and system.js.

This works great, but I need to rebuild the app each time I make a change which is not ideal. Still need to figure this one out.

Comment: Difficult to answer without more info: it could be in your `config.js` as bundler is just a wrapper around JSPM bundling and uses that to create the bundle. This means that any path resolution should be sourced from `config.js` - you should see a `bundles` section which contains a map of the files. Having said that you'd need a page to bootstrap Aurelia and if it was in the bundle, how would you bootstrap it? Do you have an MVC view which contains a `<link src='system.js'...>` and an `aurelia-app` attribute? Are you using `aurelia.enhance()` rather than the `aurelia-app` attribute?

Comment: You can use post-build events in msbuild AfterBuild targets to run aurelia cli commands

Answer (score 0):

Steve Sanderson made a template for Aurelia (that is no longer supported by Microsoft). https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/

You can also use the Aureali cli to create one.

This should work better now then in 2015.